# setInterval não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um projeto que é uma calculadora.
Ao carregar a página, gostaria de mostrar a data e a hora atual.
Adicionei o `setInterval` para atualizar a hora a cada segundo(estou mostrando hh-mm-ss) e atualizar a data automaticamente quando for preciso.

Meu código até aqui está assim:

```
class CalcController {

  constructor() {

    this._locale = 'pt-BR';
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

    //As próximas três linhas são respectivamente o elemento dos 
    //números da calculadora, a data e a hora no HTML
    this._displayCalcEl = $('#display');
    this._dateEl = $('#data');
    this._timeEl = $('#hora');

    this._displayCalc = '0';
    this._currentDate = new Date();

    this.init();
  }

  init() {

    this._displayCalcEl.innerHTML = this._displayCalc;
    this.setDisplayDateTime();
    //A parte que não está funcionando
    setInterval(() =>  this.setDisplayDateTime(), 1000);

  }

  setDisplayDateTime() {

    this._dateEl.innerHTML = this._currentDate.toLocaleDateString(this._locale, {
      day: '2-digit',
      month: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
    });
    this._timeEl.innerHTML = this._currentDate.toLocaleTimeString(this._locale);

  }
}
```

Quando a página é carregada, ele até mostra tudo que eu quero, o problema é que na hora de atualizar com o setInterval, ele não funciona.

Comment: Alterei a linha do intervalo para `setInterval(function () { new CalcController().setDisplayDateTime(); }, 1000);` e funcionou, mas eu não sei porquê....

Comment: Dependendo onde vc ta está rodando o código não vai funcionar com arrow function (=>) e com function normal vc teria que usar `bind` para injetar o escopo na function (`function(){...}.bind(this)`). Sobre arrows functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions